# Make a tab bar button open the right side menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, iiviewdeckcontroller

Say i have a tab bar with 5 ViewControllers, And a left and right menus.

My deck ViewController holds the tab bar as a center ViewController:

```
  self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[UINAVIGATIONCONTROLLER(feedController),
                                              UINAVIGATIONCONTROLLER(myProfileController),
                                              UINAVIGATIONCONTROLLER(topTradersController),
                                              UINAVIGATIONCONTROLLER(stocksListController),
                                            //  UINAVIGATIONCONTROLLER(watchlistController),
                                            ];





    self.deckController =  [[STViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:self.tabBarController
                                                                   leftViewController:settingsController
                                                                  rightViewController:watchlistController];
```

I would like to make on of the tab bar buttons open the right side menu, instead of acutely making the tabBar push that ViewController.

Say I would like the "watchlistController" tabBar button open the side menu, How could i do that?

Oh, and I'm using "IIViewDeckController" for deckController

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent a tabBarController from showing the view/viewController associated with the tab by using the`UITableControllerDelegate` and the method `- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`

Add the following to your code:

```
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
```

and then implement this:

```
#pragma mark - UITabBarControllerDelegate

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    BOOL isLeft = YES;
    if (isLeft) {
        [self.deckController openLeftView];
    }
    else {
        [self.deckController openRightView];
    }

    return NO;
}
```

This should do the trick for you.

Comment: helped me thanks, posting below swift version.

Answer (score 0):

***Swift 5 - Open SideMenu from Tabbar Item click***

This answer is a swift version of @mbogh's answer and credit goes to him for producing this trick.Please follow these steps to open side menu on tabbar item click.

```
//make your controller subclass of UITabBarControllerDelegate
extension HomeVC: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        self.openSideMenu()
        return false
    }
}

//triger tabbbar delegate from  your controller's ViewDidLoad()
self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
```